# How to add post thumbnail using joeblogs or xml-rpc?

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, joeblogs

How do I add thumbnail image content using joeblogs or xmlrpc?

add content code:

```
var post = new Post();
post.DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);
post.Title = textBox1.Text;
post.Body = richTextBox1.Text;
post.Categories = new string[] { secilikat };
var cfs = new CustomField[] 
{ 
        new CustomField() 
        { 
            // Don't pass in ID. It's auto assigned for new custom fields.
            // ID = "name", 
            Key = "post_thumbnail", 
            Value = linkToImage
        } 
};

post.CustomFields = cfs;
```

Comment: Beside on your problem, what is the point of `AddHours(0)`?

Comment: How do you upload the thumbnail and/or generate `linkToImage`?

Comment: linkToImage example http://example.com/files/2015/01/5274558.jpg @ChrFin

Comment: @sonerGönül Does the error to add at 00:00

Comment: @MuratCanGüler [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already have `00:00:00` as a time part. You don't need to use `AddHours(0)`.